# Excel - Cleaning Financial Dataset to only have latest transactions

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that is over 30,000 rows long, and about 30 columns wide. It is financial transaction data grouped by Booking. For example, Booking 123ABC may have 3 transactions – 2 invoices and 1 refund.

What I want is to have a ‘clean’ dataset that is only showing the last invoiced transactions. For example:

[image: Sampledataset]

I only want the third row (i.e. INV123-1) as the first two rows are an invoice and refund that cancels each other out.

I tried creating a macro that Deletes based on Booking and Amount, but ends up deleting the whole thing. Please help. A link to the sample dataset is as per below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eDNMwZE389_-kTnYSS_etgtFhofv-lKn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code using the right sheets and columns:

```
Sub Test()

Dim LastrowE As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

With Sheet4

    LastrowE = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastrowE To 1 Step -1
        For j = LastrowE To 1 Step -1
            If (.Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("E" & j).Value) And ((.Range("E" & i).Offset(0, 4).Value) + (.Range("E" & j).Offset(0, 4).Value) = 0) Then
                Rows(i).Delete
                Rows(j).Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple formula for finding duplicates put a filter and remove all true you will be left with the result you want.

> =COUNTIF(C4:$C$12,C4)>1

[image]